# How to write XPath for web element on eBay?

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write an XPath for the 'Electronics' link on the eBay website, but there seem to be two links with exactly the same tags and attributes:

```
<a class="rt" _sp="p2057337.m1381.l3250" href="http://www.ebay.com/rpp/electronics">Electronics</a>
```

I am using this XPath:

```
**//a[Text()='Electronics']
```

This path is giving me 2 nodes and I am not sure what else to use. Refer to the attached screenshots taken from Firebug for reference:

[image: electronics link]

[image: electronics link]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using xpath you can directly use `By.linkText()` locator.

```
driver.findElements(By.linkText('Electronics')) //but this will also give you two elements.
```

if you want to select a specific link,then you need to implement custom xpath as below.

**First link**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@id='navigatonFragment']/descendant::a[normalize-space(text())='Electronics']"));
```

**Second link**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='topnavlayer']/descendant::a[normalize-space(text())='Electronics']"));
```

Comment: well  there seems to be some error in above xpath i tried this .//*[@id='navigationFragment']/div//following::td[5]//a[@class='rt'][text()='Electronics']  its working fine but i don't want to use td[5] instead i want some thing more specific....I am new in selenium webdriver So i don't know all the path axes but trying to wrk on it so it would be helpful if u explain the functions used in your path

Comment: I checked again fixing some spell mistakes and its working fine .//div[@id='navigationFragment']/descendant::a[normalize-space(text())='Electronics']

Answer (score 0):

Both these links will work:

Link1:

```
//div[@id='navigationFragment']/descendant::a[text()='Electronics']
```

Link2:

```
//td[@data-hover-tracking='p2057337.m1381.l6435']/a[contains(@href,'electronics')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can we give like this?

```
//li[@class='hl-cat-nav__js-tab']
//a[contains (@href,'Electronics') and @xpath='1']
```

Able to highlight electronics link using this xpath.